# Is sudo-ing tomcat's startup with a non-root user the same as running it as root?

Tags: unix, tomcat

I've read that it is a security issue to run Tomcat as the root user. I want Tomcat to listen on port 80, a privileged port in Centos. I've created a user and added him to the wheel group. This user starts tomcat up with `sudo sh startup.sh`. I'm in no way an expert in unix-based OS's so I'm still confused. Have I have exposed myself to the same vulnerabilities that exist if I were to start tomcat as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using sudo to call start up script you are running tomcat as root. You're right that it's not recommended to run tomcat as root. A non root user can't bind to port 80, and there are some solutions to get around this. One way would be run tomcat as non-root, and make tomcat listen to port 8080. Enable firewall and forward requests headed towards port 80 to port 8080.

```
service iptables start

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

iptables-save
service iptables restart
```

Comment: Glad that it worked out. It's usually a good idea to keep firewall enabled. Just be careful not to lock yourself out of the machine, and punch holes into the firewall wherever needed to allow ping requests, ssh connections, HTTP ports etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are actually running Tomcat as root and this is not recommended.

You can run Tomcat directly on port 80 using [Authbind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind). It is very easy to configure on Ubuntu, I'm not sure about CentOS. You can find some instructions [here](http://java-notes.com/) (they are for Tomcat 6 but most of it is probably still true for Tomcat 7).

Alternatively you can have Apache listen on port 80 and forward requests to Tomcat on port 8080 using either `mod_proxy` or `mod_jk`.

Comment: mod_jk is recommended, in lieu of mod_proxy for running tomcat and apache on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Do be aware that the recommended solution to run [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) on port 80 is to use [mod-jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html) with the Apache web server, not to have tomcat listen on port 80 directly.