# How to hide my website port number on website url

Tags: http, tomcat, url-rewriting, port, port-number

My website has implemented by using JAVA. So we have taken VPS and installed Tomcat then deployed 
My website is appearing like this

whenever I click www.mysite.com in url ... it is appearing as below.

http://mysite.com:8080/foldername/

But I would like to see my website as www.mysite.com

Can any one suggest me what to do .. should I do any changes in htaccess file ?

Comment: You can't do this without a proxy/server on 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (or HTTPS) as those are the default port numbers. In all cases where the domain is specified and the default port is *not* used, it must be supplied as part of the URL. However, you can use `//server/relative/urls` which will use the same protocol/host/port as the current HTML page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [How to remove port number from the URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118440/how-to-remove-port-number-from-the-url)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't provide the port number in the URL your HTTP requests would be sent to port 80. You can set up a firewall rule to redirect requests headed towards port 80 to 8080.

Comment: I would like to hide port number.. it should not appear to customers... To achieve that.. we files I have to change..

Comment: Since you are using centos 6.3 just enable the firewall and add a rule to forward requests from port 80 to 8080. I have already answered this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504794/is-sudo-ing-tomcats-startup-with-a-non-root-user-the-same-as-running-it-as-root/17505346#17505346

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a port number in your URL, you have to use the default port number for HTTP, which is 80. If it's anything other than 80, you will be required to put the port number in the URL. That's all there is to it.

Now, if your question is "how do I host my Tomcat website on port 80", well there are plenty of answers to that question both on SA and teh intertubes. Just search.

Comment: Since you are using Tomcat directly, you'll have to arrange to have Tomcat listen on port 80 instead of port 8080. The solution(s) depend on your OS: Windows or UNIX?

Comment: We are using CentOS 6 ... For this OS how we have to setup ?

Comment: You can use a variety of methods. Using `jsvc` is one of the easiest. Just search for `tomcat jsvc` and you'll find lots of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to redirect all request on tomcat on default port you have to stop the IIS and use port 80 for your tomcat application or make the changes in IIS to redirect it.