# https://localhost:8443 works on Tomcat but https://localhost by itself does not work - why?

Tags: tomcat, https, localhost

Running locally on Tomcat I managed to get https working albeit with a warning from FireFox saying that I had signed the cert by myself. Fair enough, but I cannot get "`https://localhost`" to work by itself ? Is it because I have got SSL to work on the non-standard port of 8443 and if I go back and assign it to the default 443 - I will not have that problem ?

Comment: This been answered a few times, including [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189224/how-to-hide-my-website-port-number-on-website-url/19190098#comment28467074_19190098).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your problem, but if you use

```
https://localhost
```

it's implicitely the same as

```
https://localhost:443.
```

So your tomcat has to listen on 443 to make it work. Make sure you have the rights to open 443 and it's not blocked by any other service.