# i have installed two server apache and Tomcat. How I removed http://example.com:8080 to normal url or http://example.com/folder or http://example.com

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, url, url-rewriting

I have installed Apache and Tomcat Server in our domain because I have more than 25 services, some service handled by Apache and some service by handled  Tomcat. tomcat service showing http://example.com:8080, but client don't want to show 8080 port by default 80 port occupy by Apache, so **I want to remove 8080 or want to URL rewrite** I have tried to fix my problem by URL rewriting but i was unable, please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide my website port number on website url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189224/how-to-hide-my-website-port-number-on-website-url)

Comment: Dear Prashant Thanks For reply , i think you have not read my question completely, i  am two server in same hosting first Apache and second is tomcat, if i will follow above question answer then my Apache service url will be show 8080, my problem will be same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have Apache as well you can do a reverseProxy

edit httpd.conf

add at the bottom

```
ProxyPass /site1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/site1
ProxyPassReverse /site1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/site1
```

and

```
<Location /site1>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Comment: Thank you Scary for reply. after change i think 8080 will appear in Apache server, any other idea, we can change 8080 as folder name or other url ???